# Asp.net MVC unable to retrieve query string when trying to display an image in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, query-string

This is my destination page design where I am displaying image

`<img alt="" src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto", "Display")" height="50" width="50" class="photo" />`

This is my source page where I bind my `linkbutton` as follows

`@Html.ActionLink("QuestionTitle", "Index", "Display", new { QuestionID = item.QuestionID }, null)`

My destination when I perform click on the above url in the browser is as follows

`http://localhost:1931/Display?QuestionID=1`

This is my code where I am trying to display image

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetPhoto()
{
    // int quesID = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["QuestionID"].ToString()); this didn't worked so by having a look at quick watch I write the below
    int quesID = Convert.ToInt16(Request.UrlReferrer.Query.Substring(12, 1));
        byte[] photo = null;

        var usrname = (from a in db.tblQuestions
                       where a.QuestionID == quesID
                       select new { a.UserName });
        var v = db.tblUsers.Where(p => p.UserName == usrname.FirstOrDefault().UserName).Select(img => img.Photo).FirstOrDefault();
        photo = v;
        return File(photo, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

Can some one tell me how to get the `querystring` on every page I am able to get the Querystring except on this page.

Comment: Why don't you just give a parameter to your action? `public ActionResult GetPhoto(string QuestionID)`

Comment: Still not getting the ID required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your destination page you should use

```
<img alt="" src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto", "Display", new {QuestionId=Model.Id})" height="50" width="50" class="photo" />
```

(for example I supposed you have a Model with an Id property).

It's the same way you used in your source page to call *Index* Action of the *Display* Controller

Without Route data `@Url.Action("GetPhoto", "Display")` generates the link `http://localhost:1931/Display/GetPhoto`

with route data (third argument) the link generated is `http://localhost:1931/Display/GetPhoto?QuestionId=<some value>`